# RAM access on wsl2-linux

Tags: ram, wsl-2, windows-11

### Machine

I have a dell XPS15 windows 11 laptop with wsl2 running ubuntu 20.05 LTS.

### Windows

When I open `settings > system > about`, I see:

```
Installed RAM: 32.0 GB (31.8 GB usable)
```

### WSL2

When I run `htop` in my wsl2-linux(ubuntu 20.04 LTS) terminal, I see:

```
Mem 15.5 G
Swp 4.00 G
```

### Questions

1. Can I give wsl2-linux access to all my RAM ?
2. If it is possible, how can I do it ?
3. If not, what is the technical issue ?

Answer (score 1):

50 % memory is the default value. You can change it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#global-configuration-options-with-wslconfig

Run `wsl --shutdown` to shut down any active instances.
Edit `.wslconfig` in your profile directory with e.g.

```
[wsl2]
memory=30GB
```

then start wsl again.